# How to estimate fuel needed to reach LEO, GEO, and L1 earth-moon?

Tags: fuel, lox, cislunar, propellant-ratio

I'm doing some calculations about fuel production on the moon.
To get a sense of order of magnitudes involved. I'd like to know how much fuel is required to get 1kg of mass to LEO, GEO, and L1 Earth-Moon.

I'm also interested in how much fuel is required to get to L1 Earth-Moon starting from the moon's surface.

Since this is to get order of magnitudes, I can assume some representative rocket technology.

This paper may help: but not sure how to dissect it:
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0032063319301163

I think that roughly 2/3 or the propellant mass is oxidizer, is that right?

Comment: Step 1 would be to look around in this site to see how much of your question might be answered already, and step 2 would be to read Wikipedia's [delta-v](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta-v) and [Tsiolkovsky rocket equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation).

Comment: " roughly 2/3 or the propellant mass is oxidizer" depends entirely on just WHAT is being used as propellant, including even whether the propellant uses oxidizer. You really do need to specify.

Comment: "How much fuel" depends entirely on *which* propellants you use.  Please edit the question to specify.  (It also depends on factors such as drag, but we could make it a theoretical question and hand-wave those factors away.)

Comment: Your question is attracting close and downvotes because it cannot be answered as written. As other commenters have stated, this can be estimated using the "rocket equation", but you have not provided enough information to do so.  Unless you edit your question and supply the missing information, it will likely be closed (rightfully).